# Kubernetes - How to calculate resources we need for each container?

Tags: kubernetes

How to figure out how much min and max resources to allocate for each application deployment? I'm setting up a cluster and I haven't setup any resources and letting it run freely.

I guess I could use `top command` to figure out the load during the peak time and work on that but still top says like 6% or 10% but then I'm not sure how to calculate them to produce something like `0.5 cpu` or `100 MB`. Is there a method/formula to determine max and min based on `top command` usage?

I'm running two t3.medium nodes  and I have the following pods `httpd and tomcat in namespace1`, `mysql in namepsace2`, `jenkins and gitlab in namespace3`. Is there any guide to minimum resources it needs? or Do I have to figure it based on top or some other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources to be assigned to the pod depend on your application usage. For example when installing `jenkins` using helm it specified following [resource requests and limits](https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts/blob/9d0121e825f53308f5fa79689567755d49f9584d/charts/jenkins/values.yaml#L61):

```
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: "50m"
      memory: "256Mi"
    limits:
      cpu: "2000m"
      memory: "4096Mi"
```

But to avoid pod termination due to insufficient resources you can use [`Horizontal Pod Autoscaler`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) with resource metrics to scale pods up or down based on [resource consumption](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/#create-horizontal-pod-autoscaler) (or any other [custom metrics](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#support-for-custom-metrics), like requests etc.). HPA requires [`metrics-server`](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server) to be running in your cluster.

It can be easily created using [`kubectl autoscale`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#autoscale), for example:

```
kubectl autoscale deployment <deployment-name> --cpu-percent=50 --min=1 --max=10
```

Where `--min` is minimum number of replicas to be running and `--max` is the maximum replicas of the pods that will be created in case of load increase.

Comment: Didn't knew about `Horizontal Pod Autoscaler`. Could it be specified through deployment manifests?

Comment: No, it is separate resource and scales the deployment based on the `scaleTargetRef` where you specify name of the deployment, for example https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/#autoscaling-on-multiple-metrics-and-custom-metrics